# How to choose two rows in a dataframe, calculate the average of both values in each columns and add the new row with the averages in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe :

```
      col1  col2  col3
0      8     7     5
1      6     2     17
2      3     1     21
3      4     3     9
```

I want to calculate the average of each columns of row 1 and row 2 and add the new row to my pandas dataframe and get :

```
      col1  col2  col3
0      8     7     5
1      6     2     2
2      3     1     4
3      4     3     9
4     4.5    1.5   3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a `concat`:

```
pd.concat((df, df.iloc[[1,2]].mean().to_frame().T)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0   8.0   7.0   5.0
1   6.0   2.0  17.0
2   3.0   1.0  21.0
3   4.0   3.0   9.0
4   4.5   1.5  19.0
```

Or an append:

```
df.append(df.iloc[[1,2]].mean().rename(len(df)))
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0   8.0   7.0   5.0
1   6.0   2.0  17.0
2   3.0   1.0  21.0
3   4.0   3.0   9.0
4   4.5   1.5  19.0
```

Comment: however it gives 0 to the index of the row